# Formatting number into DOB

Tags: python, strftime

I need to format a number into DOB format.DD/MM/YYYY. Number is 30041986.

I am new at python. I know I need to use strftime("%m/%d/%y") maybe?

Comment: You should describe how that number decodes into a date. That includes showing the expected output for your example input

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should at least be starting with a date string, rather than an integer.  This is because should the day just be a single digit it might be lacking a leading zero in an integer representation.  Assuming we are starting with a string, we can make a full round trip to datetime and back again in the format you want.

```py
from datetime import datetime
inp = '30041986'
dt = datetime.strptime(inp, '%d%m%Y')
output = datetime.strftime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y')

print(output) # 30/04/1986
```